# Continuity with respect to initial conditions

Tags: discrete, determinism

Buridan's Ass is a paradox that I am gradually, very grudgingly, beginning to accept as not-as-silly-as-it-seems.  See [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass) and [this paper by Leslie Lamport](http://research.microsoft.com/users/lamport/pubs/buridan.pdf).  Quote: "Buridan’s Principle. A discrete decision based upon an input having a continuous range of values cannot be made within a bounded length of time."

(Bear with me; this does come around to physics.)

Now, this principle seems silly.  Consider this rule: "If I take more than 5 seconds to decide, make an arbitrary decision."  Seems simple enough.  However, the argument the paper makes is that any physical system's state at time T is (generally believed to be) a *continuous* function of (continuous) initial state X.  (See, for example, a discussion of quantum mechanics in the paper's Section 6.)  My initial counter was "chaotic systems", like weather, but I could plausibly accept that if you varied the initial conditions in sufficiently tiny increments, you might find a middle ground in the output.  That suggests, though, that varying the desirability of two choices could cause me to *indefinitely* ignore my time-based rule, even handwaving away all the human failures and weaknesses in my meat-brain.  So on the one hand, at a high level of abstract systems, it seems clear that you can set up an agent that WILL decide within bounded time, and on the other, a plausible assertion that physics does not permit this (if you zoom in to sufficiently ridiculous detail.)  (This suggests that there are wide areas of fairly mundane behaviors that cannot, perfectly, be physically implemented, even once, even in expectation.  This is somewhat troubling.)

However, this is predicated on the state of physical systems being a continuous function of their initial state.  Is this currently believed to be true, at the most fundamental level?  (Again, see for example Section 6.)  Or, are there any fundamental physical laws which, alone or in conjunction with others, that imply discontinuity, pefect decision points where an outcome either goes one way or another?

Or, can anybody think of another workaround?

(It should be noted that the paper concludes by noting that in practice the takeaway is not that decisions may take *forever*, but may and sometimes do take much longer than expected.  I still suspect it can't be infeasibly hard to design systems that at least reduce `the range of inputs leading to indecision` to a size below all plausible effect, or even precisely zero, at least in a perfectly specified system and ignoring outcomes that "don't count", such as "your system undergoes sponaneous radioactive decay all at once".)